# How do I fix? Grub issues

Tags: grub2

I made a few mistakes: I was installing Mac OS X on my hakintosh last week but Mac isn't comparable with z170 and made a Linux install to bug fix and see if that booted. Today I decided ton make a dual boot on 2 hdd Windows/Linux and made another on the same flash drive as the Mac install but different from the Linux. I have two flash drives one was Mac then Linux after format and the other was Linux from the start. The Mac then Linux after format flash drive didn't work but the plain Linux one did for whatever reason. Ubuntu 14.04... Installed but I have a Msi z170 gaming m7 and killer Ethernet e2400 and read online that Ubuntu 15... Supported it from the get go so I reformatted my things and reinstalled but here is mistake#1: I put grub on my main Windows boot not on the Partition on another hdd. So that didn't really work and Linux never booted after install. So I did bootrec.exe /fixmbr in Windows recovery and that didn't fix it so what should I do to get my Windows back without any file loss. Thanks In Advance

Comment: dude, have you __ever__ heared of _formatting_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to install linux again in the existing drive and get grub installed .

Comment: What would I select as my boot loader installation, my Windows ssd or Linux hdd. I had selected Windows earlier as per Google, later more links said to do it to Linux but damage had been done. I want to make sure what to do so I don't screw anything up. Thanks

Comment: make linux as the drive

Comment: upvote correct answer

Comment: Ok so I did it and Linux boots and I can login and use it but how do I get to Windows, can I make it act like clover where it prompts upon post?

Comment: add windows entry to grub http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_beginner_books/unofficial_ubuntu_starter_guide/index_132.html